# Forgot GPIO.cleanup() - programs not working anymore

Tags: python, gpio

I am working with a 4x7 segment display on the **RPi**. 
When I ran my python code I forgot the `GPIO.cleanup()`

Now I can't run any code because the **GPIO** is busy.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily just start another python script that only has the `GPIO.cleanup()` in it.